# Can't connect to SSH after installing xfce

Tags: ssh, linux

I've got a server (VDS) on Debian.
I have recently installed xfce (apt-get install xfce4) through SSH, and after doing that I can't login via SSH anymore.

Here is my ssh client output:

```
dmitry@dimitrios:~$ ssh -vl root 78.47.129.251
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 78.47.129.251 [78.47.129.251] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dmitry/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dmitry/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dmitry/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dmitry/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dmitry/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dmitry/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the server logs say?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you still access the server via direct connected display and keyboard. Check if the sshd_conf was changed. If that's not the reason, check out the xfce settings in Applications => Settings => Xfec4 Settings => Session and Startup.